# When is $\phi(n)=n$ true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

For what values of n is $\phi(n)=n$ true? Just looking at tables of values it seems that $\phi(n)=n$ is true only for $n=0,1$ but I cannot come up with how to  prove this.

I realize that the value of $\phi(0)$ is not really well-defined ([What is the Euler Totient of Zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226241/what-is-the-euler-totient-of-zero/1226246#1226246)) but for the purpose of this question I'll assume it is.

Comment: There is no reason even to **define** $\varphi(0)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Whether there is a reason or not, [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) says it's defined: $\phi(0)=1$.

Comment: The opinion of Alpha is of interest, but more relevant are standard books.

Comment: @AndréNicolas and yet [WolframAlpha itself](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=phi%280%29) defines $\phi(0)=0$. It seems Wolfram is being inconsistent.

Comment: For OP's question, what matters is the definition of $\varphi$ in the book/notes in which the question was asked.  As to whether one should define $\varphi$ at $0$, the question really comes down to what do the standard books do? I believe that overwhelmingly they do not define $\varphi$ at $0$. However, that needs confirmation, which is not an easy task, since there are many elementary number theory texts, in many languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, $\varphi(n)$  is defined only for $n\ge 1$. Second, if $n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^r p_i^{r_i}$  for primes $p_1,\dots,p_r$, we have:
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}n=\prod_{i=1}^r\Bigl(1-\frac1p_i\Bigr).$$
Thus, $\varphi(n)=n\iff\dfrac{\varphi(n)}n=1$ can be true if and only if $r=0$, i. e. $n=1$.

Comment: [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) says that by convention $\phi(0)=1$, so it's not only defined for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: That's pure convention. When I begun learning some number theory, it was defined for $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 5):

From the definition of $\phi(n)$ is the number of positive integers not exceeding $n$, that are relatively prime to $n$. Further, for $n>1$, we have $\gcd(n,n) = n$. Hence, for $n > 1$, we have $\phi(n) < n$. Hence, $n$ can be only $0$ or $1$.

Comment: $\phi(0)=1$ (see [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html)).

Comment: @user26486 This can be argued, and Wolfram Alpha saying so does not settle the issue.

Comment: Oops, that says Mathworld, not Alpha. Note also that it says "the Wolfram Language defines `EulerPhi[0]` equal to 0 for consistency with its `FactorInteger[0]` command."

Comment: A convention accepted by the mathematical community always has a motivation. By the way, $0!=1$ is also a convention.

Comment: @Ataulfo Yes, but $0! = 1$ is a useful convention and accepted by the mathematical community. $\varphi(0) = 1$ or $\varphi(0) = 0$ or $\varphi(0) = 2$ are not standard conventions and are not accepted by the mathematical community

Answer (score 2):

yes what you said is true $\phi(n) = n$ if and only if $n=0,1$

Now actually $\phi(n) \leq n-1$ for all $n \geq 2$ and $\phi(n) = n-1$ only occurs when $n$ is prime at this case

Comment: [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) says $\phi(0)=1\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have another proof:
For $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ with $p_i$ prime numbers, $\phi(n)=n(1-\frac{1}{p_1})(1-\frac{1}{p_2})\dots(1-\frac{1}{p_k}) < n$ as $0<1-\frac{1}{p_i}< 1\ \forall p_i$.

Comment: I've given (almost) the same answer! ;o)

Comment: Oh yes :) TLTR ( too late to read :D)

Comment: @Bernard But you unpacked it more.

Answer (score 0):

$\varphi(n)$ is the number of integers $k$, $1 \le k \le n$, relatively prime to $n$. This gives us immediately that $\varphi(n) \le n$ for all $n$.

But for $n \ge 2$, $n$ is not relatively prime to itself, so we have that $\varphi(n)$ is equivalent to the number of integers $k$, $1 \le k \le n-1$, relatively prime to $n$. Thus $\varphi(n) \le n-1$ for $n \ge 2$. In particular, the only solution to $\varphi(n) = n$ is $n = 1$. ($\varphi(0)$ is not usually defined.)

Answer (score -1):

By definition, $\phi(n)<n$ for $n\ge 2$ since, $(n,n)=n$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?! This is perfectly correct.